# How to programatically make tab bar which presents new storyboards?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uistoryboard, tabbar

I want to have a tab bar that is in every page of my application. I've separated the main 4 sections of the app(the sections on the tab) into 4 different storyboards. I now want to make the tab bar programmatically and on each click it loads up a new storyboard.

I have done similar to this tutorial: 
http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/code-examples/create-uitabbarcontroller-programmatically/

But now don't know how to turn that into loading up new storyboards instead of just view controllers?

---

While that is my main question, I'm also wondering if this is worth it. My reason for doing this is to split the storyboards up because I still want to use storyboards but I didn't want to have one massive storyboard taking over. I could however do that.

I also don't know if memory wise this isn't good as would clicking on tabs in the bar be slowed down as each time a whole new storyboard would be loaded?

Comment: How massive is your storyboard?

Comment: 4 Sections, each around 3-4 ViewControllers each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `UIStoryboard` and instantiate the initial view controller:

```
UIStoryboard(name: "TabOneStoryboard", bundle: nil)
    .instantiateInitialViewController() as! TabOneViewController
```

If you don't want to instantiate the initial view controller then create it via id:

```
UIStoryboard(name: "TabOneStoryboard", bundle: nil)
    .instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabOneViewControllerID") as! TabOneViewController
```

Remember to set the initial view controller in the storyboard's Attributes Inspector: [image: Attribute inspector]

I feel that this is a very practical approach for reducing the size of storyboards. After the view controllers are built, they should be cached with the `UITabBarController`. Don't worry about performance of the storyboard loading unless you see something get slow. Apple is pretty good about cleanup and performance with these things.

This post addresses that problem a bit: [Multiple storyboards: should I use a singleton pattern to cache them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29693848/multiple-storyboards-should-i-use-a-singleton-pattern-to-cache-them)

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a storyboard reference in your present storyboard
   [image]
2. Now in your storyboard reference set details here
   [image]
3. Now embed this storyboard reference in tabbar